The bot connects but does not play music. Discord.js V14
I wanted to make myself a music bot using ytdl in Discord.js V14, but for some reason my player does not accept activity and goes into autopaused. Here is my code for the Play command:
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, ApplicationCommandOptionType } = require('discord.js');
const { joinVoiceChannel, createAudioPlayer, createAudioResource,  generateDependencyReport} = require('@discordjs/voice');

console.log(generateDependencyReport());
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core-discord');
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,]})





module.exports = {
    name: 'connect',
    description: 'Connect the bot to the voice channel of the user who issued the command',
    options: [
        {
            name: 'query',
            type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.String,
            description: 'Enter the name of the song or the link',
            required: true,
        }],
    callback: 
    async (client, interaction) => {
        const player = createAudioPlayer();
        player.on('stateChange', (oldState, newState) => {
            console.log(`Audio player state changed: ${oldState.status} -> ${newState.status}`);
        });

        player.on('error', (error) => {
            console.error('Audio player error:', error);
        });

        await interaction.deferReply();

        if (!interaction.member.voice?.channel) {
            return interaction.editReply({ content: 'You are not in a voice channel!' });
        }

        const channel = interaction.member.voice.channel;

        try {
            const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
                channelId: channel.id,
                guildId: channel.guild.id,
                adapterCreator: channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
            });
            await interaction.editReply({ content: 'Successfully connected to the voice channel!' });

            const query = interaction.options.getString('query');
            try {
                const searchResult = await ytSearch(query);
                if (!searchResult.videos.length) {
                    return await interaction.followUp({ content: 'Failed to find videos on YouTube.', ephemeral: true });
                }

                const songURL = searchResult.videos[0].url;
                const stream = await ytdl(songURL, { filter: 'audioonly'});
                const resource = createAudioResource(stream, { inlineVolume: true });
                

                
                player.play(resource);
                
                connection.subscribe(player);


                await interaction.followUp(`Now playing: ${songURL}`);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                await interaction.followUp({ content: 'An error occurred while playing the track.', ephemeral: true });
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            await interaction.editReply({ content: 'Failed to connect to the voice channel.' });
        }
    }
};

I have that:
Core Dependencies

@discordjs/voice: 0.16.1
prism-media: 1.3.5

Opus Libraries

@discordjs/opus: 0.9.0
opusscript: 0.0.8

Encryption Libraries

sodium-native: not found
sodium: not found
libsodium-wrappers: 0.7.13
tweetnacl: not found

FFmpeg

version: 6.0-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev
libopus: yes

I checked the robotability of the stream and it works, the bot connects to the channel, displays a message about turning on the song, but it does not play anything itself. Even the green circle doesn't light up.
I also displayed an error that occurs when the player's status is playing:
     Audio player error: {
      status: 'buffering',
      resource: AudioResource {
        playStream: Encoder {
          _readableState: [ReadableState],
          _events: [Object: null prototype],
          _eventsCount: 7,
          _maxListeners: undefined,
          _writableState: [WritableState],
          allowHalfOpen: true,
          encoder: OpusEncoder {},
          _options: [Object],
          _required: 3840,
          _buffer: <Buffer >,
          [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
          [Symbol(kCallback)]: [Function: bound onwrite]
        },
        edges: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
        metadata: null,
        volume: VolumeTransformer {
          _readableState: [ReadableState],
          _events: [Object: null prototype],
          _eventsCount: 8,
          _maxListeners: undefined,
          _writableState: [WritableState],
          allowHalfOpen: true,
          _readInt: [Function (anonymous)],
          _writeInt: [Function (anonymous)],
          _bits: 16,
          _bytes: 2,
          _extremum: 32768,
          volume: 1,
          _chunk: <Buffer >,
          [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
          [Symbol(kCallback)]: [Function: bound onwrite]
        },
        encoder: Encoder {
          _readableState: [ReadableState],
          _events: [Object: null prototype],
          _eventsCount: 7,
          _maxListeners: undefined,
          _writableState: [WritableState],
          allowHalfOpen: true,
          encoder: OpusEncoder {},
          _options: [Object],
          _required: 3840,
          _buffer: <Buffer >,
          [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
          [Symbol(kCallback)]: [Function: bound onwrite]
        },
        audioPlayer: AudioPlayer {
          _events: [Object: null prototype],
          _eventsCount: 2,
          _maxListeners: undefined,
          _state: [Object],
          subscribers: [Array],
          behaviors: [Object],
          debug: [Function (anonymous)],
          [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
        },
        playbackDuration: 0,
        started: true,
        silencePaddingFrames: 5,
        silenceRemaining: -1
      },
      onReadableCallback: [Function: onReadableCallback],
      onFailureCallback: [Function: onFailureCallback],
      onStreamError: [Function: onStreamError]
    }

